Find the partial derivatives of the generalized eigen-system w.r.t. the parameter vector?
The problem is described as:

For array signal processing applications, there are many such optimization function as
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{\nu }} \boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}\boldsymbol{\nu },\mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu }=1
$$
where I would like to explain that $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}$ denotes the known block-diagonal received signal matrix
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 \hat{\boldsymbol{R}}_1&  &  \\
 &  \ddots&  \\
 &  &  \hat{\boldsymbol{R}}_L\\
\end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{C} ^{ML\times ML}
$$
where $\hat{\boldsymbol{R}}_l, l=1,\dots,L$ is the received signals from $L$ arrays (If you don't know, just think of them as $L$ different, but known, received signals.)
and $\boldsymbol{\varPsi}$ is a block-diagonal matrix of known form but containing the parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ we need to solve for:
$$
\boldsymbol{\varPsi }=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 \boldsymbol{\varPsi }_1\left( \boldsymbol{\eta } \right)&  &  \\
 &  \ddots&  \\
 &  &  \boldsymbol{\varPsi }_L\left( \boldsymbol{\eta } \right)\\
\end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{C} ^{ML\times ML}
$$
and there is a form vector of $L$ unknown complex weight vectors:
$$
\boldsymbol{\nu }=\left[ \boldsymbol{w}_{1}^{\mathrm{T}},\cdots ,\boldsymbol{w}_{L}^{\mathrm{T}} \right] \in \mathbb{C} ^{ML\times 1}
$$
We known that this cost function is a quadratic minimization problem with quadratic constraints, which can be constructed using the Lagrange multiplier method:
$$
L(\boldsymbol{\nu },\mu )=\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}\boldsymbol{\nu }+\mu \left( 1-\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu } \right) 
$$
Making its gradient with respect to $\boldsymbol{\nu}$ to $0$ yields
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}\boldsymbol{\nu }=\mu \boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu }
$$
it means that multiplier $\mu$ is the generalized eigenvalue of the matrix pencil $\left\{ \hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}},\boldsymbol{\varPsi } \right\}$.
and we can get
$$
\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}\boldsymbol{\nu }=\mu \boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu }
$$
Due to the constraint $\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu }=1$, it obtains
$$
\mu = \boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}\boldsymbol{\nu }
$$
Lastly, the optimization function convert to
$$
\lambda _{\min}\left\{ \hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}},\boldsymbol{\varPsi } \right\} ,\mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.\boldsymbol{\nu }^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{\varPsi \nu }=1
$$
Therefore, we can find the estimated $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ by searching the grid points by the spectrum function
$$
P\left( \boldsymbol{\eta } \right) =\lambda _{\min}\left\{ \hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\varPsi } \right\} 
$$

I would like to take the partial derivative of the generalized eigenvalue with respect to $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ to assess this algorithm performance, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{\eta }}\lambda _{\min}\left\{ \hat{\boldsymbol{\varGamma}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\varPsi }\left( \boldsymbol{\eta } \right) \right\} 
$$
Since I have not been exposed to this area of math, I am wondering if there is currently a way to get a closed expression for the final partial derivative? Or are there any references that you can share? I will be sure to cite them and would appreciate any replies that you may have! Thanks!
